# Open/Close NHibernate Session

Tags: c#, nhibernate, session

Using FluentNHibernate in a web application, I've created a singleton SessionFactory class to have the ability of the following:

```
SessionFactory.Instance //returns ISessionFactory
```

Is it common/best practice to open/close sessions as follows?

```
using(ISession session = SessionFactory.Instance.OpenSession())
{
    using(ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        //some operation
    }
}
```

The above code would live in the respective repository classes for a given entity.

I've noticed there is a theme of creating a HttpModule to open the session at the start and stop of the application, but I'm wondering if this is situational or more common.

**UPDATE**

Going forward with the HttpModule, I have a similar thought:

With a repository class, I'm basically doing the following(config uses WebSessionContext):

```
using(ISession session = SessionFactory.Instance.GetCurrentSession())
{
    using(ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        //some operation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using a web application I would recommend using the HttpModule to open a session and close it on a request cycle. The session factory I would probably instantiate on the Application_Start.

For the repository objects I would pass the session to it via a constructor.

I personally don't think a repository object has enough information in order to decide what to do with the session.

Comment: Right on. I was originally discouraged due to my lack of knowledge on the WebSessionContext, but the HttpModule(begin/end) functionality seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 8):

I think this would depend on your conversation

- session-per-request
- session-per-request-with-detached-objects
- session-per-conversation

for more information about that [look here](https://www.hibernate.org/42.html)

Here are some links on implementations

- [Nhibernate with Ninject](http://jasondentler.com/blog/2009/08/part-7-nhibernate-and-ninject-for-asp-net-mvc/) < session managed in global asax
- [DAO, Reposities etc](http://jasondentler.com/blog/2009/09/part-8-daos-repositories-or-query-objects/) < shows the types, with links. then a implementation

note the session can be injected into the Doa/respository.

for a complete architecture have a look at [sharp architecture](http://www.sharparchitecture.net/) < this is based on best practice, and i would reconmend it highly

[Summer of Nhibernate](http://www.summerofnhibernate.com/) ep 13, is about sessions with Asp.Net